# Is there a way to do a (continuous) moving average with Spark's dataframes and Window.partitionBy?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a large time series dataset, and would like to be able to calculate a moving average of some reading in it. The order of magnitude is around 50 Hz and a few days of data per file.

I know I can do a moving average of a reading against its surrounding few seconds of readings using a Window:

```
window_avg = Window.orderBy("time").rowsBetween(-100,100) # Just using 100 for example
res = df.withColumn("avg", avg("reading").over(window_avg)).sort("time")
```

However, I read that without defining a partition this will run on a single executor. To avoid this, I could define a partition like so:

```
window_avg = Window.partitionBy("hour").orderBy("time").rowsBetween(-100,100)
res = df.withColumn("avg", avg("reading").over(window_avg)).sort("time")
```

But in this case, the first few rows of each partition will not refer to the preceding rows of the preceding partition.

Is there a way in spark to either define overlapping window partitions, or to have something like `rowsBetween` refer to previous partitions? I believe I've seen posts about doing something similar with RDDs, but not with Window partitions.

For reference, here's a simplified example set of data:

```
minute,time,reading
1,1.57,1
1,1.58,2
1,1.59,3
2,2.0,2
2,2.1,3
2,2.2,2
2,2.3,5
2,2.4,9
2,2.5,2
```

I can do a rolling average of the readings like so:

```
df = spark.read.csv('foo.csv', header=True)

window_avg = Window.partitionBy("minute").orderBy("time").rowsBetween(-1,1)
res = df.withColumn("avg", avg("reading").over(window_avg)).sort("time")
print res.collect()
```

I would want the following output:

```
 [Row(minute=u'1', time=u'1.57', reading=u'1', avg=1.5), 
  Row(minute=u'1', time=u'1.58', reading=u'2', avg=2.0), 
  Row(minute=u'1', time=u'1.59', reading=u'3', avg=2.3333333333333335), 
  Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.0', reading=u'2', avg=2.6666666666666665), 
  Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.1', reading=u'3', avg=2.3333333333333335), 
  Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.2', reading=u'2', avg=3.3333333333333335), 
  Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.3', reading=u'5', avg=5.333333333333333), 
  Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.4', reading=u'9', avg=5.333333333333333), 
  Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.5', reading=u'2', avg=5.5)]
```

But with the `partitionBy` on 'minute' I get:

```
[Row(minute=u'1', time=u'1.57', reading=u'1', avg=1.5), 
 Row(minute=u'1', time=u'1.58', reading=u'2', avg=2.0), 
 Row(minute=u'1', time=u'1.59', reading=u'3', avg=2.5), 
 Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.0', reading=u'2', avg=2.5), 
 Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.1', reading=u'3', avg=2.3333333333333335), 
 Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.2', reading=u'2', avg=3.3333333333333335), 
 Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.3', reading=u'5', avg=5.333333333333333), 
 Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.4', reading=u'9', avg=5.333333333333333), 
 Row(minute=u'2', time=u'2.5', reading=u'2', avg=5.5)]
```

With a partition, at the boundary, the avg at time 1.59 has an incorrect average, and for 2.0 has an incorrect average too.